# Inserting sorted values from one MySQL table into another table

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, `average_table` and `position_table`. They have two column each. I would like to copy sorted data from `average_table` into `position_table` as shown below

The `average_table` looks like this

```
std_id       avr
001          23.4
002          34.7
003          13.9
004          56.8
```

then the `position_table` should look like this:

```
std_id      avr
004         56.8
002         34.7
001         23.4
003         13.9
```

When I used the following sql queries, the result was no different between `average_table` and `position_table`. Can some one help me out please?

```
try {
    String str = "insert into POSITION_TABLE select * from AVERAGE_TABLE ORDER BY avr DESC";
  rs = st.executeQuery(str);
}
catch(SQLException ce){System.out.print(ce)}
```

Answer (score 2):

In the SQL world rows aren't really sorted. There might be a way to do this in MySQL (in SQL server, I think a clustered might do it - but for another reason than getting the rows in order).

In other words, an inserted row is not guaranteed to have a specific order. As SQL is declarative, you have to declare how to order it when you query.

I don't understand what you're trying to achieve with the `position` table - to me it looks like an exact duplicate of the `average` table and you're getting the data in ranked order already with your query using the order by. Just use order by when you need the data ordered.

Comment: when you say world, you mean physical ?

Comment: @ddmps  then how can I overcome the above problem please?

Comment: @Manu What is the actual problem?

Comment: if your *only* motivation for inserting into position_table is to get data by position, than as **ddmps** said, that is just a query, and ditch the concept of a position_table.

Comment: @ddmps when I run the above sql querry, the data was copied from position_table to avarage_table, but it was not sorted as needed. The two tables contains the same unsorted data. Tha is the problem

Comment: @Manu In SQL, there is no such thing as sorted data 'from scratch'. SQL orders it when you command to order it. You can simply use the same select statement when you need sorted data instead of duplicating all the values (which is a pretty bad design choice, IMO). Just use: `select * from AVARAGE_TABLE ORDER BY avr DESC`.

Comment: OK, thank you for that, it is a mistake I mean ordered  data

Answer (score 1):

```
create table average_table
(   std_id int not null,
    avr decimal(8,2) not null
);
insert average_table (std_id,avr) values (1,23.4),(2,34.7),(3,13.9),(4,56.8);

create table position_table
(   id int auto_increment primary key,
    std_id int not null,
    avr decimal(8,2) not null
);

insert into position_table(std_id,avr) select std_id,avr from average_table order by avr desc;

select * from position_table;
+----+--------+-------+
| id | std_id | avr   |
+----+--------+-------+
|  1 |      4 | 56.80 |
|  2 |      2 | 34.70 |
|  3 |      1 | 23.40 |
|  4 |      3 | 13.90 |
+----+--------+-------+
```